# select distinct col1 with min(col2) and max(col3) from table

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

My table looks like this with duplicates in col1

```
col1,      col2,      col3,      col4
1,            1,            0,            a
1,            2,            1,            a
1,            3,            1,            a
2,            4,            1,            b
3,            5,            0,            c
```

I want to select distinct col1 with max (col3) and min(col2);
so result set will be:

```
col1,      col2,      col3,      col4
1,            2,            1,            a
2,            4,            1,            b
3,            5,            0,            c
```

I have a solution but looking for best ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT col1, MAX(col3) AS col3, MIN(col2) AS col2, MAX(col4) AS col4
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY col1;
```

You showed in your example that you wanted a `col4` included, but you didn't say which value you want.  You have to put that column either in an aggregate function or in the `GROUP BY` clause.  I assumed that taking the max for the group would be acceptable.

---

**update:**  Thanks for the clarification.  You're asking about a variation of the greatest-n-per-group problem that comes up frequently on Stack Overflow.  Here's my usual solution:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t3
 ON t1.col1 = t3.col1 AND t1.col3 < t3.col3
WHERE t3.col1 IS NULL;
```

In English: show me the row (`t1`) for which no row exists with the same `col1` and a greater value in `col3`.  Some people write this using a `NOT EXISTS` subquery predicate, but I prefer the `JOIN` syntax.

Here's the output from my test given your example data:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    1 | a    |
|    1 |    3 |    1 | a    |
|    2 |    4 |    1 | b    |
|    3 |    5 |    0 | c    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Notice that there are two rows for `col1` value 1, because both rows satisfy the join condition; no other row exists with a *greater* value in `col3`.

So we need to add another condition to resolve the tie.  You want to compare to rows with a *lesser* value in `col2` and if no such rows exist, then we've found the row with the least value in `col2`.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MyTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable t3
 ON t1.col1 = t3.col1 AND t1.col3 < t3.col3
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable t2
 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col3 = t2.col3 AND t1.col2 > t2.col2
WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL AND t3.col1 IS NULL;
```

Here's the output from my test given your example data:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    1 | a    |
|    2 |    4 |    1 | b    |
|    3 |    5 |    0 | c    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

PS: *By the way, it's customary on Stack Overflow to edit your original question and add detail, instead of adding answers to your own question that only clarify the question.  But I know some actions aren't available to you until you have more than 1 reputation point.*

Comment: Gets my vote for not having an unnecessary table alias, but you miss out on bonus points in not naming your column outputs :)

Comment: @sidereal: Point taken.  I have edited to add column aliases.